# Extract lines containing certain value or greater

Tags: text-processing, numeric-data

I am working with a log file that contains entries that appear like this:

```
$Hostname1:  0x7FDBF4B1AB10 (  23698) waiting 100 seconds, NSDThread: for I/O completion on disk vd4
$Hostname2:  0x7F2D10A2F8C0 (  25393) waiting 200 seconds, NSDThread: for I/O completion on disk vd35
$Hostname3:  0x7F2D109F4290 (  25343) waiting 900 seconds, NSDThread: for I/O completion on disk vd11
$Hostname4:  0x7FDBF4B1AB30 (  23698) waiting 100 seconds, NSDThread: for I/O completion on disk vd40
$Hostname5:  0x7F2D10A2F830 (  25392) waiting 750 seconds, NSDThread: for I/O completion on disk vd13
$Hostname6:  0x7F2D109F4240 (  25342) waiting 500 seconds, NSDThread: for I/O completion on disk vd14
```

I would like to filter the lines where the wait time is greater than an arbitrary value (let's say 600 seconds). What's the best way to do this in bash?

Answer (score 13):

This `awk` will get you what you want.

```
awk '$6 > 600 { print }' file

$Hostname3:  0x7F2D109F4290 (  25343) waiting 900 seconds, NSDThread: for I/O completion on disk vd11
$Hostname5:  0x7F2D10A2F830 (  25392) waiting 750 seconds, NSDThread: for I/O completion on disk vd13
```

or per @Kusalananda, this line is enough

```
awk '$6 > 600 ' file
```

Comment: You may drop the `{ print }` bit if you wish.

Comment: There's a certain value in keeping `{ print }` under some circumstances, which is that it's helping to clarify the code.  This becomes important when multiple people with varying degrees of `awk` knowledge needs to understand exactly what's happening. Particularly (not applicable here though), this may be the case when most avid `awk`-ers may want to use `1` in place of `{ print }` in a piece of `awk` code.  To a non-initiated, this may be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Goro's reply is fine. Just to secure the test about the number between `()` that could fill the space

```
awk -F '[ \t(]+' '$5 > 600' file
```